# What is the difference between this.variable = function() and var variable = function() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me if there are a core weird difference between the following two ways of exposing public function in Javasctipt. Both of them seems to do the job for me, but I need to know if there are weird detail I'm missing.

```
function Class1 () {
  this.canProcess = function(line) {
    return line != null;
  };
}

function Class2() {
    var canProcess = function(line){
      return line != null; 
    }

    return {
      canProcess: canProcess
    }
}

var obj1 = new Class1(); 

console.log(obj1); 

var obj2 = new Class2(); 

console.log(obj2);
```

Attached is plunker, I print the results, both looks the same to me. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/RUFGa3JxTAbAH83t?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that when you explicitly return an object from the constructor, the instance will be *just that object*. It won't inherit from the class's prototype, nor will it have a `.constructor` property of the class.

For your exact code, there's no difference, but there could be a difference in other situations. For example:

```js
function Class1 () {
  this.canProcess = function(line) {
    return line != null;
  };
}
Class1.prototype.fn = () => console.log('fn');

function Class2() {
    var canProcess = function(line){
      return line != null; 
    }

    return {
      canProcess: canProcess
    }
}
Class2.prototype.fn = () => console.log('fn');

var obj1 = new Class1();
// Instance inherits from class prototype:
console.log(typeof obj1.fn); 
// Instance has constructor property of class:
console.log(obj1.constructor === Class1);

console.log('----');

var obj2 = new Class2(); 
// But obj2 is just a plain object, no connection to Class2 or Class1.prototype:
console.log(typeof obj2.fn);
console.log(obj2.constructor === Class2);
```